# Random MethodNotFoundExepection in ComosDB? Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, azure-cosmosdb

for the last few days, I have seen this error message - when trying to access my ASP.net Identity hosted in CosmosDB - This code really hasn't changed in over a year I don't know why all of a sudden it has started burping.

Here is the code in my start up class that initializes the connection to DocumentDB and ASP.net Identity (I am using full framework 4.6.1 (upgrading to core by year end) - document.db client 1.7.1 (which was working until a few days ago - like a champ)

```
        services.AddSingleton<IDocumentClient>(InitializeDocumentClient(
         new Uri("https://recipesavants.documents.azure.com:443/"),
         "REDACTED"));
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddIdentity<DocumentDbIdentityUser, DocumentDbIdentityRole>()
            .AddDocumentDbStores(options =>
            {
                options.Database = "recipes";
                options.UserStoreDocumentCollection = "users";
            }).AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    private DocumentClient InitializeDocumentClient(Uri endpointUri, string authorizationKey)
    {
        // Create a DocumentClient and an initial collection (if it does not exist yet) for sample purposes
        DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(endpointUri, authorizationKey, new ConnectionPolicy { EnableEndpointDiscovery = false });

        try
        {
            var db = client.ReadDatabaseAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri("recipes")).Result;
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            throw ae;
        }

        try
        {
            // Does the Collection exist?
            var collection = client.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("recipes", "users")).Result;
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            throw ae;
        }
        return client;
    }
```

and here is the stack trace -- 
this is very random - and if I kill the browser it appears to work again

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.IDocumentClient.ReadDocumentAsync(System.Uri, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.RequestOptions)'.
   at RecipeSavants.Identity.DocumentDb.Tools.DocumentDbExtensions.d__1`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at RecipeSavants.Identity.DocumentDb.Tools.DocumentDbExtensions.ReadDocumentAsync[T](IDocumentClient client, Uri documentUri, RequestOptions requestOptions)
   at RecipeSavants.Identity.DocumentDb.Tools.DocumentDbExtensions.d__0`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at RecipeSavants.Identity.DocumentDb.Stores.DocumentDbUserStore`2.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1.d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Elmah.Io.AspNetCore.ElmahIoMiddleware.d__5.MoveNext()
```